# Combining two scripts into one

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have two scripts. Both scripts are on the same server (**serverA**)

The first one (**serverA**) makes an ssh connection to the other server (**serverB**), and executes the second script,

e.g

```
*script1*
ssh $ipaddress var="$var1" "bash -s" < $script2
```

*script2* then executes on **serverB**.

Is there a way to combine these into one script? So it would start by making the ssh connection, then execute the rest of the script, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Make an SSH Connection to another server
ssh $ipaddress

#Now Execute the rest of the script
do stuff here . . .
and here . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh $ipaddress /bin/bash <<END
do stuff here . . .
and here . . .
END
```

Comment: FYI OP, this is called a [here-document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Answer (score 0):

assumming `script2` in local dir

```
#!/bin/bash
if scp script2 $ipaddress:/tmp
then
   ssh $ipaddress /tmp/script2 "arg" >& /my/result.$ipaddress
   ssh $ipaddress rm /tmp/script2 
fi
```

you'll pay an extra transfert, but if `script2` is non trivial (e.g. not just a `tail` or `wc` ), it might be worth.